# Show that if $B$ is an $n \times m$ matrix of rank $m$, there exists $m \times n$ matrix $A$ s.t. $AB$ is the identity matrix of $m$

Tags: matrices

Show that if $B$ is an $n\times m$ matrix of rank $m,$ there exists $m\times n$ matrix $A$ such that $AB$ is the identity matrix of $m$

I'm starting to lag behind, and I have no idea where to start with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we have $n \geq m$ (why?). Since $B$ has rank $m$, so does $B^T$, and therefore we have
$$\text{Range}(B^T) = \mathbb{R}^m.$$
For $i = 1,2,\ldots,m$, pick $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that 
$$B^T x_i = e_i.$$
Let $A = (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_m)^T \in \mathbb{M}_{m\times n}$. Then
$$B^TA^T = I_m \implies AB = I_m.$$